# How to give two or where condition in mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, select, where-clause

i need to run a query something similar to this

```
select * from users where (username='abc' or email='abc@gmail.com') and password='123'
```

How to do that in codeigniter? I tried something like,

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where("email = '" . $email . "'");
    $this->db->or_where("username = '" . $email . "'");
    $this->db->where("password = '" . $password . "'");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Here user may insert value for username as email or username. So need to check username field value both in email field and username field with password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->where("(email = '" . $email . "' OR username = '" . $email . "') ");
  $this->db->where("password = '" . $password . "'");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
  $this->db->where("(username='abc' or email='abc@gmail.com')");
```